# Add trusted File Share to internet explorer

Tags: powershell

I need a bit of help, I need to add my File Share \169.254.100.100\Share to the trusted Sites in IE, I did it the manual way, so I know that is working. But I'd like to do it also in PS. I tried adding it in the Registry and GPO in different ways but failed. For websites it works but not for the Server.. any suggestions?

```
New-Item -Path '.\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' -Name \\169.254.100.100\Share

New-ItemProperty -Path '.\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains' -Name\\169.254.100.100\Share -Value 1 -PropertyType Dword
```

But this fails which is ok but I don't have other ideas.
BR Tim

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding an IP Address it goes in the Ranges subkey not the Domains subkey, you also need to specify the file URL scheme and populate the ZoneMapKey. The parent subkeys may not exist, on my test PC even ZoneMap was not present. The example below should be expanded to test what exists and what needs creating.

```
Set-Location "HKCU:"
New-Item -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\' -name ZoneMap
New-Item -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' -name Domains
New-Item -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap' -name Ranges
New-Item -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges' -name Range1
New-ItemProperty -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1' -Name ":Range" -Value "169.254.100.100"
New-ItemProperty -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges\Range1' -Name "file" -Value 2

New-Item -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\' -name ZoneMapKey
New-ItemProperty -Path '\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -Name "file://169.254.100.100" -Value "2"
```

You'd need to make sure Range1 doesn't exist and find RangeN where N doesn't exist.